# How to kill jni process which derived from java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, twain, morena

I want to connect sharp network scanner using morena api and twain. Everything is ok if scanner is reachable but when scanner is not reachable, jni library opens a select scanner window. I think it is twain ds screen, I want to disable this screen. If scanner is not reachable, I want to throw error instead of open select device window. When I stop application, this screen also close so I think it depends on java thread. Question is, how can I stop this window's thread without stop whole program. I can run main method in another thread, and I can find this thread id, but when I stop this thread it is not close select device window.

```
import SK.gnome.morena.Morena;
import SK.gnome.morena.MorenaException;
import SK.gnome.morena.MorenaImage;
import SK.gnome.morena.MorenaSource;
import SK.gnome.twain.TwainManager;
import SK.gnome.twain.TwainSource;

import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloWorld
{ public static void main(String[] args) throws MorenaException
  {

    TwainSource[] list = null;

    try {
      list = TwainManager.listSources();
    } catch (Exception var4) {
      list = null;
    }



    MorenaSource source= list[1];
    System.err.println("Selected source is "+source);
    if (source!=null)
    { source.maskUnsupportedCapabilityException(false); // Lesson 3
      source.maskBadValueException(false);              // Lesson 3
      source.setVisible(false);                         // Lesson 2
      source.setColorMode();                            // Lesson 2
      source.setResolution(300);                        // Lesson 2
      ((TwainSource)source).setUnits(TwainSource.TWUN_CENTIMETERS);
      source.setFrame(0, 0, 7.8, 10.5);
      System.err.println("Image resolution is "+source.getResolution());
      MorenaImage image=new MorenaImage(source);
      System.err.println("Size of acquired image is "
           +image.getWidth()+" x "
           +image.getHeight()+" x "
           +image.getPixelSize());
    }
    Morena.close();
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you ever want the window itself to pop up?  If not you can try `TwainManager.getDefaultSource()` instead of hardcoding `list[1]`, or `TwainManager.listSources()` to either build your own selection or evaluate for 0 results and throw your own error.

To use `TwainManager.getDefaultSource()`:

```
MorenaSource source = TwainManager.listSources();
```

See Morena's [TWAIN JTP Support](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp_support.html) for more info.